# Unwanted Script being added to all HTML pages in all browsers

Tags: html, windows, virus

I don't know why but this has been happening for a while now:

In every browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE) there is always a script attached at the end of the code.
That's the script:

```
http://cupons.dantis.com.br/api/app/landing.php?app=QUMtMjItMEItQkQtODAtQUQ=&aff=999999&partner=999999
```

It's an adware or something, I blocked the domain `coupons.dantis.com.br` on my hosts file only so the php script won't run and gather my personal info.

But the script is always there anyways, I have tried unninstalling the browsers and the extensions, I have removed many programs that seemed suspicious, nothing.

I ran Junkware Removal Tool, AdwCleaner, antivirus, Malware Bytes.

I'm desperate.

I need to track the process behind this script inclusion or a way to block it trough the browser.

Image:
[image]

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: I've asked for help in SU also, I didn't notice I was sending it here. But since I need a script blocker, perhaps SO will be handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it!

There was a process called `viva.exe`

I tracked down the folder where the exe was at, and closed the process. Then deleted the file.

The script is gone.

Comment: I believe others may find the same problem in the future. That's the solution, folks!

Comment: Note that this may not be enough. If there's any actual malicious installed software, service, Startup entry it could come back pretty easily. Also this should really be on SU.

Comment: mark ur answer as accepted